# BigQuery - Time difference from previous row if customer ID matches

Tags: google-bigquery, timedelta

I have an order table which looks roughly like this

```
consumerID || TransactionDate || Revenue
1          || 2015-01-01      || 55
1          || 2015-02-01      || 65
2          || 2015-01-01      || 10
3          || 2015-03-01      || 20
4          || 2015-01-01      || 25
4          || 2015-01-01      || 45
4          || 2015-03-01      || 55
```

I would like to add a column that works out the time in months that it took the customer to place the next order so that the data would look like

```
consumerID || TransactionDate || Revenue || OrderCount || TimeInMonths
1          || 2015-01-01      || 55      || 1          || null
1          || 2015-02-01      || 65      || 2          || 1
2          || 2015-01-01      || 10      || 1          || null
3          || 2015-03-01      || 20      || 1          || null
4          || 2015-01-01      || 25      || 1          || null
4          || 2015-01-01      || 45      || 2          || 0
4          || 2015-03-01      || 55      || 3          || 2
```

I have figured out how to work out the running count of orders for a customer using the following

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY o.ConsumerID ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC) OrderNumber,
```

I would like to do something similar but work out the months difference and i am stumped.

What i want is

If it is the 1st order, or the earliest date the customer is seen this is null.
If order number 2 calculate the difference from the 1st, if the 3rd calculate from the 2nd and so on in months.

If it makes it easy I can ensure the data is sorted by consumerId and Transaction date

Comment: Oh god sorry, i thought i had. I'm so sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ConsumerID, TransactionDate, Revenue, OrderCount,
  DATEDIFF(TransactionDate, prevTransactionDate) AS TimeInDays,
  INTEGER(DATEDIFF(TransactionDate, prevTransactionDate)/30) AS TimeInMonths
FROM (
  SELECT ConsumerID, TransactionDate, Revenue, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ConsumerID 
        ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC) OrderCount,
    LAG(TransactionDate) OVER(PARTITION BY ConsumerID 
        ORDER BY TransactionDate ASC) prevTransactionDate
  FROM YourTable 
) ORDER BY ConsumerID, TransactionDate
```

Calculation in Days is obvious. Calculation in Months requires you to set business logic of how to calculate it from diff in days. Above is sample rule applied.